# Checkbox checked inside asp.net GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp.net grid view and i have `IsActive` field in database and it comes as 1  or 0.So i need according to that value Grid view Checkbox is checked or not.

### Grid View Field

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsActive" DataField="ISACTIVE" HeaderText="Is Active"  runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ISACTIVE") %>'/>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

### Code Behind

```
 GridRes gridRes = NewsProxy.GetAllnews(req);
            gv.DataSource = gridRes.Dataset;
            gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `IsActive` field is a `bit` column and contains only `0` or `1` then you can do like below in order to pre-check or unchech the `checkbox`.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsActive" DataField="ISACTIVE" HeaderText="Is Active"  runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ISACTIVE")) %>'/>
```